# Getting the css id of an element on mouse hover from an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a plugin (extension) that is able to web scrape given a URL and the id of the element. I was wondering if there is a way to get the CSS id of an element from a tab on chrome on hovering the mouse over it. Most of the docs and tutorials show `document.getElementById('name');` but here you have to provide the Id so I was wondering if there was any dynamic way of getting it on mouseover.

Any suggestions and reference docs would be of great help. Thanks.